# Centering Google Map around points from a store - Sencha Touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a map component with Google Maps in a view that I want to dynamically set the center of. It is on a details-style page so data is passed to it when it is loaded so setting the center within the launch function would be preferrable. I keep getting a series of undefined error when trying to reference the map and using Google Maps setCenter() function doesn't work when targeting the Sencha map component. I'm pretty sure using setCenter is the best way to accomplish this but I just can't seem to target and execute it.

Any advice on this would be great, thanks in advance:

Map code (an item inside an Ext.Container):

```
       {
             xtype: 'map',
             height: 150,
             itemId: 'map',
             width: '100%',
             mapOptions : {
                zoom : 12,
                mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                navigationControl: true,
                navigationControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
                }
             } 
        }
```

Comment: how are you trying to get map for calling setCenter ?

Comment: @Viswa I have managed to get the data I want to update the map with from the store, but regarding actually targeting the map and executing the setCenter function I'm not too sure, which is why I was asking for some help.

My only attempt so far have been trying to get the map through Ext.getComponent which didn't work.

Comment: do you have id for Container ?

Comment: @rixo answer is good enough for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the provided [`setMapCenter`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Map-method-setMapCenter) method.

You can use a [component query](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) to get a reference to your map. If you really can't get it this way, give it an `id` and use `Ext.getCmp(yourId)` (not recommended).

Take care that the map has actually been rendered before doing that (put your update logic in a [`maprender`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Map-event-maprender) listener).

```
yourContainer.down('#map').setMapCenter({latitude, longitude});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Would the maprender listener be in my controller or the view itself?

Comment: Both would work. I would put it in the controller because it doesn't seem like internal view logic.